# How to use AOP with Feign calls

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, feign

I am interested in how to use Feign client in AOP.  For example:

**API:**

```
public interface LoanClient {
    @RequestLine("GET /loans/{loanId}")
    @MeteredRemoteCall("loans")
    Loan getLoan(@Param("loanId") Long loanId);
}
```

**Config:**

```
@Aspect
@Component // Spring Component annotation
public class MetricAspect {

    @Around(value = "@annotation(annotation)", argNames = "joinPoint, annotation")
    public Object meterRemoteCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, 
                        MeteredRemoteCall annotation) throws Throwable {
    // do something
  }
}
```

But I do not know how to "intercept" the api method call. Where did I go wrong?

**UPDATE:**

My Spring class annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MeteredRemoteCall {

    String serviceName();
}
```

Comment: Where does the `@Component` annotation come from? From Spring maybe? If so, do you use Spring AOP or AspectJ? How do you compile the code? And where does `@MeteredRemoteCall` come from? A special library or is it your own annotation? Can you please show the annotation source code? I think I know the answer to your question, but it depends on your answers to my questions.

Comment: @kriegaex yes `@Component` annotation its Spring class, 
Updated my question with new class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your situation is somewhat complex because you have several problems:

- You use Spring AOP, an "AOP lite" framework based on dynamic proxies (JDK proxies for interfaces, CGLIB proxies for classes). It only works for Spring beans/components, but from what I see your `LoanClient` is not a Spring `@Component`.
- Even if it was a Spring component, Feign creates its own JDK dynamic proxies via reflection. They are outside the control of Spring. Probably there is a way to wire them into Spring manually, either programmatically or via XML configuration. But there I cannot help you because I do not use Spring.
- Spring AOP only supports a subset of AspectJ pointcuts. Specifically, it does not support `call()` but only `execution()`. I.e. it only weaves into the place where a method is executed, not the place where it is called.
- But the execution takes place in a method implementing an interface and annotations on interface methods such as your `@MeteredRemoteCall` are never inherited by their implementing classes. In fact, method annotations are *never* inherited in Java, only class-level annotations from class (not interface!) to respective subclass. I.e. even if your annotation class had an `@Inherited` meta annotation, it would not help for `@Target({ElementType.METHOD})`, only for `@Target({ElementType.TYPE})`. **Update:** Because I have answered this question several times before, I have just documented the problem and also a workaround in [Emulate annotation inheritance for interfaces and methods with AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607015/emulate-annotation-inheritance-for-interfaces-and-methods).

So what can you do? The best option would be to [use full AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) (load-time weaving) from within your Spring application. This enables you to use a `call()` pointcut instead of `execution()` which is implicitly used by Spring AOP. If you use `@annotation()` pointcuts on methods in AspectJ, it will match both calls and executions, as I will show you in a stand-alone example (no Spring, but the effect is the same as AspectJ with LTW in Spring):

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MeteredRemoteCall {}
```

**Feign client:**

This sample client grabs full StackOverflow question pages (HTML source code) as strings.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import feign.Param;
import feign.RequestLine;

public interface StackOverflowClient {
    @RequestLine("GET /questions/{questionId}")
    @MeteredRemoteCall
    String getQuestionPage(@Param("questionId") Long questionId);
}
```

**Driver application:**

This application uses the Feign client interface in three different ways for demonstration purposes:

1. Without Feign, manual instantiation via anonymous subclass
2. Like #1, but this time with an extra marker annotation added to the implementing method
3. Canonical usage via Feign

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import feign.Feign;
import feign.codec.StringDecoder;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackOverflowClient soClient;
        long questionId = 41856687L;

        soClient = new StackOverflowClient() {
            @Override
            public String getQuestionPage(Long loanId) {
                return "StackOverflowClient without Feign";
            }
        };
        System.out.println("  " + soClient.getQuestionPage(questionId));

        soClient = new StackOverflowClient() {
            @Override
            @MeteredRemoteCall
            public String getQuestionPage(Long loanId) {
                return "StackOverflowClient without Feign + extra annotation";
            }
        };
        System.out.println("  " + soClient.getQuestionPage(questionId));

        // Create StackOverflowClient via Feign
        String baseUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        soClient = Feign
            .builder()
            .decoder(new StringDecoder())
            .target(StackOverflowClient.class, baseUrl);
        Matcher titleMatcher = Pattern
            .compile("<title>([^<]+)</title>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            .matcher(soClient.getQuestionPage(questionId));
        titleMatcher.find();
        System.out.println("  " + titleMatcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

**Console log without aspect:**

```
  StackOverflowClient without Feign
  StackOverflowClient without Feign + extra annotation
  java - How to use AOP with Feign calls - Stack Overflow
```

As you can see, in case #3 it just prints the question title of this very StackOverflow question. ;-) I am using the regex matcher in order to extract it from the HTML code because I did not want to print the full web page.

**Aspect:**

This is basically your aspect with additional joinpoint logging.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.MeteredRemoteCall;

@Aspect
public class MetricAspect {
    @Around(value = "@annotation(annotation)", argNames = "joinPoint, annotation")
    public Object meterRemoteCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MeteredRemoteCall annotation)
        throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println(joinPoint);
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**Console log with aspect:**

```
call(String de.scrum_master.app.StackOverflowClient.getQuestionPage(Long))
  StackOverflowClient without Feign
call(String de.scrum_master.app.StackOverflowClient.getQuestionPage(Long))
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.2.getQuestionPage(Long))
  StackOverflowClient without Feign + extra annotation
call(String de.scrum_master.app.StackOverflowClient.getQuestionPage(Long))
  java - How to use AOP with Feign calls - Stack Overflow
```

As you can see, the following joinpoints get intercepted for each of the three cases:

1. Only `call()` because even with manual instantiation the implementing class does not have the interface method's annotation. So `execution()` cannot be matched.
2. Both `call()` and `execution()` because we manually added the marker annotation to the implementing class.
3. Only `call()` because the dynamic proxy created by Feign does not have the interface method's annotation. So `execution()` cannot be matched.

I hope this helps you understand what happened and why.

Bottom line: Use full AspectJ in order to let your pointcut match against `call()` joinpoints. Then your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!
Can you provide dependencies that you use ? aspectjr and aspectweaver ?

Comment: May be I cant catch calls of Feign method because I use Spring Boot ?

Comment: For full AspectJ you need to compile your aspect code with the AspectJ compiler (Ajc), either from command-line or via e.g. AspectJ Maven plugin which in turn uses _aspectjtools.jar_ for compilation. For LTW you need _aspectjweaver.jar_ as a Java agent. How to exactly use it from Spring is explained in the link I provided in my answer, I guess. _aspectjrt.jar_ is smaller than _aspectjweaver.jar_ and not needed for LTW because the runtime is already contained as a subset in the weaver jar. The runtime jar is needed for compile-time weaving which is my preferred method to use AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late but it can be worked in an easier way. Your code was correct just a tiny bug was there. You should use @within instead of @annotation. I mean the correct code is something like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component // Spring Component annotation
public class MetricAspect {

@Around(value = "@within(package.path.MeteredRemoteCall)", argNames = "joinPoint")
public Object meterRemoteCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  // do something
  }
}
```